# Power calculation for simplification?

Tags: exponentiation, education

I have this simple question I saw [here](http://www.dspguide.com/ch4/3.htm):

`±(2 - 2^(-23)) × 2^128` = `±6.8 × 10^38`

How did they get to `±6.8 × 10^38` ?

I tried :

`(2 - 2^(-23)) × 2^128`  $\Longrightarrow$ `(2^1 - 2^(-23)) × 2^128` $\Longrightarrow$ `2^129 - 2^(105)` $\Longrightarrow$ now what ?

Comment: Don't forget "log".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore the insignificant part $2^{105}$ first

$$
x = 2^{129} \\
\log_{10} x = 129 \times \log_{10}2 \approx 38.83286944 \\
\therefore x \approx 10^{38.83286944} = 10^{0.83286944} \times 10^{38} \approx 6.805647 \times 10^{38}
$$

Similarly, we can get $2^{105} \approx 4.056 \times 10^{31}$.

Comment: But then , again I get `4.056*10^31 - 4.056^(31)`... which is not a single value.....

Comment: @RoyiNamir sorry, I don't quite catch you. In this answer I mean we can separately calculate `2^129(=6.805647*10^38)` and `2^105(=4.06*10^31=0.000000406*10^38)`, and then do the minus: `(6.805647-0.000000406)*10^38`. Is there any problem?

Comment: does `X^y-Z^y==(X-Z)^y` ????

Comment: @RoyiNamir **of course not**. I just **separately** calculate `X^y`  and `Z^y`, and then do the subtraction.

Comment: I meant this : `(6.805647-0.000000406)*10^38` - but I get my confusion - it's not a power but a magnitude of 10 which is why this is legit

Comment: @RoyiNamir `6.805647*10^38 - 0.000000406*10^38 = (6.805647-0.000000406) * 10^38`. Please distinguish "multiplication" and "power" :)

Comment: offline - are you familier with floating point representation ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Not quite. But for further information about that, I suggest you read wikipedia pages about [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), ["float"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format), and ["double"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format). If you have any problem on these issues, it may be better to ask it on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Something very useful is to notice that $2^{10} = 1024 \approx 10^3$
You calculations are almost correct (wrong sign in front of 105) but you can neglect $2^{105}$ because it is very small compared to $2^{129}$ So :$$2^{129} = 2^9(2^{10})^{12}\approx 512\times (10^3)^{12} = 5.12\cdot 10^2\times10^{36}$$

This way you can find a very good estimate of you answer with light calculations.

If you really want to find the $6.8$ instead of $5.12$, then use the fact that $(1+x)^n\approx 1+nx$ for small $x$ ie :$$1.024^{12} \approx 1 + 0.024*12 = 1.288$$

$1.024^{12}$ is what I neglected in my above approximation so if you plug that in the result I had above you obtain:
$$2^{129} \approx 1.288 \times 5.12\times10^{38} \approx 6.6\times 10^{38}$$

By taking a better approximation of $1.024^{12}$ you can achieve the wanted result.
What is nice with this method is that there is no need for a calculator, all the calculations can be done by hand easily.

Comment: this `(1+x)^n => 1+nx` is amazing. I didnt know that.

Comment: Approximately and for small $|x|<1$ only. Here's the full expansion : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%281%2Bx%29^n

Comment: (You need to copy the whole link including "^n")